# How to avoid repetition when overriding a method?

Tags: java, oop

For example I have a parent class:

```
public class Parent {
    public String getString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

And a group of subclasses override getString() and return the same result:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return a string";
    }
}

public class Child2 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return a string";
    }
}

public class Child3 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return a string";
    }
}
```

Another group of subclasses return the same result too:

```
public class Child4 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return nothing";
    }
}

public class Child5 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return nothing";
    }
}

public class Child6 extends Parent {
    @Override
    public String getString() {
        return "return nothing";
    }
}
```

So the result is, I have to write the same implementation for overriding getString() many time. Is there any better way than this ?
Thank you very much for any reply.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `Parent` is not `abstract` and also doesn't just implement the repetitive method?

Comment: You could write one implementation in Parent and only override in the other implementation classes...

Comment: Well there is no particular reason. Parent can be abstract. I just make an example

Comment: brso05: If I do that, then I still need to do the override 3 times, right ?

Comment: No; if you make the class abstract and implement the redundant method there, then so log as you don't override it, it will have the same functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find yourself doing this, it's a good case for creating another class in the hierarchy that performs common logic like this, and leaves the per-subclass stuff up to the subclasses. For example, in your case, you might have something like:

```
public class Parent {
    public String getString () { return ""; }
}

public class StringlessChild extends Parent {
    @Override public String getString () { return "nothing"; }
}

public class StringedChild extends Parent {
    @Override public String getString () { return "a string"; }
}
```

And have the child classes inherit the appropriate base (e.g. child 1-3 extends `StringedChild`, 4-6 extend `StringlessChild`).

In general, having a lot of duplicate functionality means there is something significantly common about the behavior of those children, which is a sign that a common root that implements that behavior might be appropriate.

Note that things like abstract bases, or interfaces, may be in order here as well (as pointed out in some of the question comments), the examples above just stick to your simplified / contrived example for clarity.

Comment: Forgot to have the subclasses `extend Parent`

Comment: And to fill that thought out -- if you have two sets of methods, `getString()` and `getFoo()`, where the "another class" divide doesn't match (ie, there are some classes that use getString-A but getFoo-B), then it _may_ be that your class should be split into two separate classes, each of which has its own hierarchy. In other words, it could be an indication that your class is trying to do too many things.

Comment: I think the Parent class should be abstract since `getString()` method is overridden in all children.

Comment: @TheMetalBeard Probably, in this strange little unrealistic example, but like I tried to get across in the last paragraph, that isn't really the meat of this question or in the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this - use another layer in between:

```
public class Parent {
    public String getString() {
        return "";
    }
 }

 //This class can be abstract even the parent is not.
 public abstract class Intermediate1 extends Parent {
     public String getString() {
        return "Do something";
     }
 }

 public class Child1 extends Intermediate1 {
     //Do something here
     //The getString method is inherited and will return "return a string"
 }
 //Do the same for Child2 and Child3
```

So for the second return value you just can add another Intermediate class and do not need to repeat the code:

```
 public abstract class Intermediate2 extends Parent {
     public String getString() {
        return "return another string";
     }
 }

 public class Child4 extends Intermediate2 {
     //Do something here
     //The getString method is inherited and will return "return another string"
 }
 //Do the same for Child5 and Child6
```

Comment: What is the advantage of making `Intermediate2` an abstract class? I think making Parent an abstract class is a better solution since `getString()` method gets overridden everywhere anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an abstract class (if there is no actual functionality provided, consider making this into an Interface):

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public abstract String getString();
}
```

Then, I would extend it as many times as there are different implementations you need:

```
public class Child1 extends Parent {
    public String getString(){
        return "return a string"
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Child2 extends Parent {
    public String getString(){
        return "return nothing"
    }
}
```

and then subclass those children:

```
public class Child3 extends Child1 {
    //other methods, variables... etc. 
    //no need to override getString(). It will return "return a string"
}
```

and

```
public class Child4 extends Child2 {
    //other methods, variables... etc. 
    //no need to override getString(). It will return "return nothing"
}
```